# Automate number format system changes in Excel through vba for bilingual users

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

For those who use biligual reports, it's a headache to change the number system frequently.

I have the code to change number from *english* to *arabic* back and forth.

But I need to find what is the current system status whether english or arabic.

Is there a way to know this?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use `Application` object

```
Set lg = Application.LanguageSettings
MsgBox lg.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDInstall) 'this will return the code of the language based on the parameter given to LanguageID method
```

The parameter can be either one of the following

- `msoLanguageIDExeMode`=4: Execution mode language.
- `msoLanguageIDHelp`=3: Help language.
- `msoLanguageIDInstall`=1: Install language.
- `msoLanguageIDUI`=2: User interface language.
- `msoLanguageIDUIPrevious`=5: User interface language used prior to the current user interface language.